# Access VBA FSO.FileExists Commands fails in ACCDE on one computer, works in another

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm writing an MS Access VBA app and having a mind boggling error. I have a development machine with MS-Access 2007 installed, and a end user machine with Access 2007 runtime installed. I'm writing the app to be compiled into an ACCDE and run on the end user machine.

I have a file that I need to programatically create a link to, since the location always changes based on a serial number. I've written code to do this, and it works find as both an ACCDB and ACCDE file on the dev machine. However, when I run the ACCDE on the end user machine, my method of determining if the file exists throws an error, causing the if statement to fail, and therefore the file never opens. My code (with some debug code) is as follows:

```
Sub Import(FileType As String, FileLocation As String)

10 On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

20 Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim fso As FileSystemObject

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

' Re-link the CSV Table
30 Set db = CurrentDb

50 db.TableDefs.Refresh

60 Dim teststr As String, testloc As String

70 teststr = FileLocation & "\" & FileType & ".csv"

MsgBox teststr
testloc = "N:\Data\111\111_01\result\result.csv"

80 If fso.FileExists(teststr) Then
       MsgBox "TEST"
90     DoCmd.TransferText acLinkDelim, , "dataTbl", testloc, True
100    db.TableDefs.Refresh
    'DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide                
110 Else
120     MsgBox ("Results File does not exist.")
    Exit Sub
140 End If
170 db.Close:   Set db = Nothing

PROC_ERR:
180     MsgBox "Error Line: " & Erl & vbCrLf & _
            "Error: (" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description, cbCritical
End Sub
```

File Location = "N:\Data\111\111_01\result where N is a mapped network drive (same drive letter on both machines)

File Type = "result"

I cannot figure out why fso.FileExists errors out only on the ACCDE on one computer. I've tried a similar check with the DIR command and similarly got "Error 52".

If I replace teststr with testloc (such that the path is hardcoded) it works fine on all machines, yet if I compare the values of teststr and testloc they are identical.

I'm at my wit's end. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm curious, you said that that the string is the exact same between teststr  and testloc. Yet they behave differently, I can see how that makes no sense at all.  The path I tend to follow when something makes zero sense is that I missed something.  So if you do an If teststr = testloc then msgbox "Matching string" or something to that effect, does it pass the check?

Comment: Is the mapped drive actually *connected* when the code runs, or just mapped?

Comment: I would check differences in references.

Comment: Just for the note: I my code I create FSO's using `CreateObject`: `Dim fso As Object` and then `Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`. Should help you get over references issues.

Comment: I recall something about the FSO not being operational in an Access runtime-only environment. Perhaps that is the case?